# Using grep to search text document

Tags: grep

I'm using `grep` to search a document and print off occurrences of a specific username and only their clock in entries. I can get it to do one or the other, but not both. And once it's found the two words `username` and `clock in` I need to print off the first line of each entry (containing the date and time).

For example, the entries into the text documented are formatted as follows:

```
2014-10-05 21:01:00
username
CLOCK IN
```

I've been trying to get through this command for the past couple hours, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Provide some sample input and desired output, together with what you tried. Otherwise it is a bit difficult to understand the question... and you won't get many answers.

Comment: Sorry if my message was confusing. I want to read in the username, then have the program look for that username and only the clock in entries, then print the output to the screen. Here's what I have right now, which isn't working: read $USERnAME           grep "${USERNAME}" timeclock.txt |grep "CLOCK IN"

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks to all who helped. `read $USERNAME
grep "${USERNAME}" timeclock.txt | grep -B2 "CLOCK IN"`

Comment: Nice! You could even post an answer with it, so next people checking the question will see the answer that worked to you. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
awk -v user="FreddyFrog" '/:/{t=$0} /^CLOCK IN/ && lus~user {print t} {lus=$0}' file
```

So, you pass the name you are looking for in as `user` - I have set it to look for `FreddyFrog` here. The script then looks for lines with a colon in them and assumes they are the time, and saves the time in the variable `t`. It then looks for lines that start with `CLOCK IN` and if found, checks the last user we saw go by was the one you are looking for - if it is, we print the time `t`. On all other lines, we assume the line is a username and save it in a variable `lus` which I use to mean `last user seen`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! 'read $USERNAME grep "${USERNAME}" timeclock.txt | grep -B2 "CLOCK IN"'